# How to know the interface specs to pass into node.js http.Server

Tags: node.js

All:

I am pretty new to socket.io, when I go thru its Docs( the Express 3/4 part especially ), there is an example:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(80);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

What I am trying to understand is this line:

```
var server = require('http').Server(app);
```

The Doc here: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_server
makes me even more confused, I wonder could anyone give a little detail how to read those docs(both **Node.js** and **Express.js** APIs) and How to find out what that "app" should looks like so that it can be passed into `require('http').Server` ?

Thanks

Comment: it creates `app` on the previous line. its the express app.

Comment: @Robbie Thanks, my confuse is about how do I know what "the express app" looks like? So if I use other library build that "app", how do I know if I can pass it to require('http').Server? ( comparing with JAVA Doc: each java param has a type extended or an interface implemented)

Answer (score 0):

It's all a bit confusing but the basic contract of `http.Server` is it expects a request handler function that accepts 2 arguments: `req, res`. The `app` object express creates for you is actually a function and actually designed to be used as an http request handler, so it all works together, but it can be quite confusing because in addition to being a function, of course `app` instance is a complex object representing an entire express application so it has lots of other properties. But something as simple as `function (req, res) { console.log('Request received')}` would work just fine as an argument to `http.Server`.

Another way to connect the dots would be to do this and confirm that things actually still work fine:

```
var server = require('http').Server(function (req, res) {
  app(req, res)
});
```

Then you realize that your function is just passing arguments through to `app` unmodified and is thus unnecessary.